# How to get ORDS Prehook documentation and example

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I didn't find enough documentation and examples about **prehook** implementations in Oracle ORDS.

In the implementation I would like to know how to get a Http Header param, with user code and then to do a `SELECT` to verify the user can to be access (authorization).

When no access, it needs to return an error with code 403 (forbidden).

Comment: Read this and if you have more questions let me know https://www.jmjcloud.com/blog/using-the-ords-prehook-function

Comment: Thanks, very nice documentation and it references the Oracle documentation about prehook too: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/18.4/aelig/developing-REST-applications.html

Comment: Is there a way to get pathparam from url with get_cgi_env? Example: `https://clientes/{codigo}`. I would like to get the value from `:codigo` pathparam.

Comment: Yeah just reference :codigo directly in your handler code

Comment: Only into handler GET, POST, PUT, etc. on endpoint then. Inside the prehook there is no way to get pathparam, right?

Comment: Start a new post... With your new question

Comment: New post created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70276275/get-path-param-value-into-ords-prehook