# Get path param value into ORDS prehook

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-ords

Is there a way to get pathparam from url with get_cgi_env? Example: `https://clientes/{codigo}`. I would like to get the value from `:codigo` pathparam.

Into handler GET, POST, PUT, etc. on endpoint it is possible to get the pathparam value but it's not clear how can to be done into ORDS prehook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this function to get the complete url - the "QUERY_STRING" portion should give you the parameters

```
  FUNCTION request_url RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    l_url VARCHAR2(1024);
  BEGIN
    l_url := owa_util.get_cgi_env('SERVER_NAME') ||':' ||
           owa_util.get_cgi_env('SERVER_PORT') ||
           owa_util.get_cgi_env('SCRIPT_NAME') ||
           owa_util.get_cgi_env('PATH_INFO') ||
           owa_util.get_cgi_env('QUERY_STRING');
    RETURN l_url;
  EXCEPTION WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
    RETURN 'unable to retrieve request_url';
  END request_url;
```

Comment: I created your function `request_url` into `rest_pk_util` package. After I created an ORDS endpoint like '\x\test' with SQL `select rest_pk_util.request_url() from dual;`. This throws 'unable to retrieve request_url' exception.

Comment: If I use owa_util directly into ORDS endpoint like `select owa_util.get_cgi_env('QUERY_STRING') from dual` it throws the Exception: *The request could not be processed because an error occurred whilst attempting to evaluate the SQL statement associated with this resource. Please check the SQL statement is correctly formed and executes without error. SQL Error Code: 6502, Error Message: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 354*

Comment: try putting it in pl/sql instead of sql

Comment: Right, it's works in pl/sql.

Comment: On this specific question, we can't really get the name of the path param, we just have the url already with values.
For example: `/clientes/{codigo}` I don't have a `:codigo` param names and its values. I can only get the url filled with values, `/clientes/123456`

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the CGI variables available via owa.cgi_var_name and owa.cgi_var_val (owa.num_cgi_vars for the count).

I have this running in my preHook:

```
pragma autonomous_transaction;
l_obj  json_object_t := json_object_t();
l_json blob;
  begin
    for i in 1 .. owa.num_cgi_vars loop
      l_obj.put(owa.cgi_var_name(i), owa.cgi_var_val(i));
    end loop;
    l_json := l_obj.to_blob;
    insert into rest_access
      (id, created, cgi_variables, current_schema)
    values
      (s_rest_access.nextval, sysdate, l_json, sys_context('userenv', 'current_schema'));
    commit;
```

Lots of values that you have access to, including parameters.

To see a list of parameters after running it and logging requests, simply run

```
select *
  from json_table((select json_dataguide(cgi_variables, dbms_json.format_flat) from rest_access),
                  '$[*]' columns( --
                          opath varchar2(200) path '$."o:path"',
                          otype varchar2(40) path '$.type',
                          olength number path '$."o:length"')) j;
```