# How to get host name and request headers for ORDS RESTful Services?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have Oracle 18c database with Apex 19.2.

I created an ORDS RESTful Service to receive some POST requests from another application.

I need to get some detailed informations about the request sent to my RESTful service.

So I'm using the implicit parameters documented here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/18.3/aelig/implicit-parameters.html#GUID-E7716042-B012-4E44-9F4C-F8D3A1EDE01C

For example : **:body**, **:content_type**...

```
declare
        RequestBodyReceived blob;
begin
        RequestBodyReceived := :body ;
        insert into SomeTable (RequestBody) values (RequestBodyReceived);
        :status_code := 201;
end;
```

[image]

This is nice but I can't find other informations about the request. Mainly the sender host, the headers, etc.

How can I get sender Host and Request headers?

Comment: owa_util.get_cgi_env gives you quite a bit of info, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70276275/get-path-param-value-into-ords-prehook)

Comment: @KoenLostrie thanks for your response. It seems like your answer gives information about my server. What I'm looking for is information about the remote server sending the request to my ORDS Service

Comment: That example indeed shows information about the request itself, but I believe owa_util package can get all header information. Use owa_util.print_cgi_env to find out what header information is available initially and then cherry pick the ones you need. Tim Hall has a good [blog](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-http-headers-and-ords-specific-bind-variables) about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code as an endpoint source to check all available CGI variables.

```
begin
    for i in 1..nvl(owa.num_cgi_vars, 0) loop
        htp.p(owa.cgi_var_name(i) || ': ' || owa.cgi_var_val(i));
    end loop;
end;
```

I found it some time ago on the Internet, but I don't remember where was it.